# Dynamic Placeholders Not Working in Sitecore 9

Tags: dynamic-placeholder

I have this code nested down 3 deep in placeholders i.e. /MainFrame/ContentMain/ and then there is this Dynamic Placeholder I am wanting to use:

```
<!-- Right Content -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
    @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("ContentSectionRight")
</div>
```

I have not used Dynamic Placeholders for Sitecore 9 yet so I am unsure how to set this up in the rendering. I am using /MainFrame/ContentMain/ContentSectionRight but that is not working, and my component is not showing up. I know my component is working because if I move i to /MainFrame/ContentMain it will show up.

What is the correct way to render my component using the NEW Dynamic Placeholders in Sitecore 9?

Comment: Are you adding the component via the experience editor or presentation details and typing the placeholder key in?

Comment: I am adding in via the Presentation Details from the Content Editor at this point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key for a dynamic placeholder uses the parent unique rendering Id to become dynamic, it also appends an incremental number in case you want multiple placeholders. In your example:

```
<!-- Right Content -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
    @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("ContentSectionRight")
</div>
```

So you have created a placeholder key of `ContentSectionRight` - when you add a component to that via the experience editor, you will notice that the key becomes `ContentSectionRight-{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}-0`- obviously, the guid of its parent rendering unique Id will be added in there.

If you want to add a component via presentation details, you will need to look in the `__Renderings` or `__Final Renderings` raw values to get the Id that would be used. It is usually a lot easier to just use the Experience Editor to add your components.

Comment: After looking into your first comment about using the Experience Editor, that is exactly what I did, and it added it in correctly. Then I went over to the Final Layout in the Presentation Details in the Content Editor and voila, there was the key as such: /MainFrame/ContentMain/ContentSectionRight-{393B1F3D-763A-470C-8848-E65E2043DFD1}-0. This is different from the "_" as Sitecore uses dashes, but nonetheless 99% correct, and is marked as the answer. Much agreed, use the Experience Editor for adding your components as the Primary unless situations dictate otherwise. Thanks Richard!

Comment: Updated to use the hyphens

Comment: Now 100% correct. Thanks again Richard and happy coding!